# First subsection in chapter 2 gets the number 2.0.2 which should be 2.0.1

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\subsection{should be 1.0.1}
\chapter{2}
\subsection{should be 2.0.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\subsection` should go after `\section`, that's the cause, the section number is **0**, you just jumped over one level of sectioning and there's no reseting of the subsection number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't happen in a new system (with a latex from 2015). In older systems load the fixltx2e package:

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\subsection{should be 1.0.1}
\chapter{2}
\subsection{should be 2.0.1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First note: I don't recommend the omittance of `\section`!!!!

But here's a way to get the counting and counter resetting as the O.P. requests.

Use the `\usepackage{chngcntr}` package and `\counterwithin*{subsection}{chapter}` -- this will reset the `subsection` counter each time `chapter` is changed and preserves the predefined `\thesubsection` counter format, that's why I used the starred version `\counterwithin*`.

The standard format for subsection counter output is

`\thesection.\arabic{subsection}`
The section format will in turn use `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`,

`\thesubsection` is the same as

```
\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}
```

then.

As long as there's no `\section` (or no explicit `\setcounter{section}{...}`), the section counter is `0` and this will appear in `\thesubsection` of course.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{subsection}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\subsection{should be 1.0.1}
\chapter{2}
\subsection{should be 2.0.1 and is 2.0.1 now}
\end{document}
```

Honestly, the `0` does not look nice in the numbering.